# issue with access 2007 reports - images not displayed

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an access 2007 application that has a few reports.
With some of the reports the images in the footer are displayed when I go into print preview or print the report.
But with others I can see the images in design view, but when I go to print preview I cannot see them.

Is there a setting or something that you can set to a report that doesn't show the images in a report?

I read some where, it's something to do with the printer drivers, but since the images work in some reports, I don't think that is the case

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When the report is displayed, there is a check box at the very top ribbon that says 'Print data Only', that was ticked, once unticked the images were displayed.